# Clone DIV de uma página para outra

Tags: div, append, clone

Olá estou com dificuldades em copiar o menu lateral da pagina inicial para a pagina de categoria, normalmente utilizo o comando a abaixo para copia de div para a mesma pagina, porém para pagina diferentes nao estou conseguindo

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.pagina-inicial .menu.lateral.fechado.borda-principal').clone().appendTo($('.pagina-categoria .coluna.span3.esquerda'));
});
```

não sei se preciso alocar as informações em outro lugar e depois jogar na pagina que quero ou fazer uma cópia direta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não pode fazer isso com Javascript porque requer tratamento do tipo server-side. Javascript é apenas para o cliente, só vai funcionar para a mesma pagina.

O que você pode fazer é em um arquivo js padrão que será utilizado em todas as páginas, criar o menu lateral no Javascript e incluir em um elemento que existirá em todas as páginas.

Eu utilizei o jQuery. É só adicionar a biblioteca no head do seu documento.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**O mesmo pode ser feito no Javascript puro, basta chamar a função no window.onload.**

> De forma simples, seria algo assim:

Html

```
<div id="areaDoMenu">

</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#areaDoMenu").append(
          '<ul>' +
            '<li>Item 1</li>' +
            '<li>Item 2</li>' +
            '<li>Item 3</li>' +
            '<li>Item 4</li>' +
            '<li>Item 5</li>' +
          '</ul>');
});
```

Veja aqui > http://jsfiddle.net/Lc0eprhs/

Comment: ah sim, compreendi, acontece que o site que estou desenvolvendo pertecente a uma plataforma que ja tem um modelo, eu só estou melhorando o layout, para ficar mais atrativo, e eles tem 2 modelos de menu lateral, que variam nas paginas do site, sendo um desse modelos que eu queria tirar, e deixar somente o modelo da pagina inicial para as demais paginas, bom agradeço a atenção, vou analisar e ver se desenvolvo um outro menu e aplico